# Can't post on friend's wall from my app

Tags: ios, facebook

This question has frequently been asked over stackoverflow.com but none of the answers work for me. What i need to do is to post on the wall of user's friend from within my app. I have included stream_publish to the list of permissions so it must work but it doesn't.

What i have already tried is:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
[params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];
[params setObject:@"Yet another text" forKey:@"attachment"];
[params setObject:@"1234567890" forKey:@"target_id"];

[facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
       andParams: params
     andDelegate: self];
```

but when the dialog window pops up it tell me "An error occured with MyAppName. Please try again later."

Also i tried

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[1234567890]/feed" 
                       andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test wall post" forKey:@"message"]
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];`

but it just does nothing. What am i doing wrong? Can anyone correct me?

Comment: Are you sure this friend hasn't locked his/her wall from friend's posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved it. The problem was incorrect parameters for action links.

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:FB_APP_ID forKey:@"api_key"];
[params setObject:@"User message prompt" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];

[params setObject:@"531370682" forKey:@"target_id"];

NSArray *actionLnks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Action Links", @"text", @"http://football.ua",@"href", nil], nil];
NSString *actionStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLnks];

NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Attachment name", @"name",
                            @"Attachment caption", @"caption",
                            @"Attachment description", @"description",
                            @"http://football.ua", @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

[params setObject:actionStr forKey:@"action_links"];
[params setObject:attachmentStr forKey:@"attachment"];

[facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
       andParams: params
     andDelegate: self];
```

Answer (score 0):

The error gives me the idea that it's just a temporary Facebook thing.

It also happens with the normal facebook interface every now and again. And last few days I've also been noticeing weird errors with the Graph API.

Comment: no, your idea is wrong. i know that cause i can post on my friend's wall from within DrawSomething. it's something different